# Parsing array of objects to format data

Tags: javascript, json, loops, ecmascript-6, netlify-cms

I have an array of cities with this structure (given from the CMS):

```
  const cities = [
    {
      city: 'Genova',
      coordinates: '{\'type\':\'Point\',\'coordinates\':[8.9473343,44.4023918]}',
      countryIsoCode: 'it',
      description: 'test',
      isInitialCity: true,
    }, {

      city: 'Barcelona',
      coordinates: '{\'type\':\'Point\',\'coordinates\':[2.0951271,41.3397004]}',
      countryIsoCode: 'es',
      description: 'description',
      isInitialCity: false,
    }, {
      city: 'Sydney',
      coordinates: '{type\':\'Point\',\'coordinates\':[151.2158203,-33.8704156]}',
      countryIsoCode: 'au',
      description: 'Sydney description',
      isInitialCity: false,
    }];
```

I want to parse the `coordinates` position to get a more scalable object and get its properties nesting.

This is what I've tried:

```
cities.map(city=>JSON.parse(city.coordinates))
```

But when I print it seems to have no effect. However, if I manually print a position like `console.log(JSON.parse(cities[0].coordinates))` it shows a formatted result like is shown in the following screenshot:

[image]

How can I make it automatically via loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This is what I've tried:
>
> ```
> cities.map(city=>JSON.parse(city.coordinates))
> ```

`map()` created you a brand new, separate array with the coordinates only, which you have thrown away afterwards.

> However, if I manually print a position like `console.log(JSON.parse(cities[0].coordinates))` [...] How can I make it automatically via loop?

Well, put it in a loop:

```
for(let city of cities)
  city.coordinates = JSON.parse(city.coordinates);
```

---

However your example data is syntactically incorrect, there are `,}`-s at the end of the objects (after the `true`/`false`), and the supposed JSON data is not JSON, like

```
{type':'Point','coordinates':[151.2158203,-33.8704156]}
     ^it has no pair, and it should be double quote anyway, all of them
{"type":"Point","coordinates":[151.2158203,-33.8704156]} <-- this is JSON
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Is there a way to use a one-line loop (`forEach`, etc)?

Comment: `for..of` is a "more one-line loop" than `forEach()` in my opinion, but otherwise yes: `cities.forEach(city->city.coordinates=JSON.parse(city.coordinates));`

Answer (score 1):

```js
 const cities = [
    {
      city: 'Genova',
      coordinates: '{\'type\':\'Point\',\'coordinates\':[8.9473343,44.4023918]}',
      countryIsoCode: 'it',
      description: 'test',
      isInitialCity: true,
    }, {

      city: 'Barcelona',
      coordinates: '{\'type\':\'Point\',\'coordinates\':[2.0951271,41.3397004]}',
      countryIsoCode: 'es',
      description: 'description',
      isInitialCity: false,
    }, {
      city: 'Sydney',
      coordinates: '{type\':\'Point\',\'coordinates\':[151.2158203,-33.8704156]}',
      countryIsoCode: 'au',
      description: 'Sydney description',
      isInitialCity: false,
    }];
     
    //for(let city of cities)
 // city.coordinates = JSON.parse(city.coordinates);
    
    
    var x=cities.map(city=>JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(city.coordinates)))
   
   
   console.log("result :"+(JSON.stringify(x)))
```

```
  //   result :["{'type':'Point','coordinates':[8.9473343,44.4023918]}","{'type':'Point','coordinates':[2.0951271,41.3397004]}","{type':'Point','coordinates':[151.2158203,-33.8704156]}"]
```

Answer (score 1):

What I think might be happening is that you're doing the map right but not returning the result.

For example `mynumbers.map(num => num++)` won't actually effect `mynumbers` at all. You have to assign the result of the `map` to another variable...

```js
const parsedCities = cities.map(city=>JSON.parse(city.coordinates))
```

Now your new `parsedCities` variable will look like you want it to and the original `cities` array will remain unchanged.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, the return is under ` =>` when using a one-line statement.